# Customize piwik widgets in iframe - seriesPicker, legend, styles

Tags: matomo

My piwik version is 2.14.1.
I am integrating Piwik widgets via iframe in my website. This is an example link:

`myPiwik/index.php?module=Widgetize&action=iframe&moduleToWidgetize=VisitsSummary&actionToWidgetize=getEvolutionGraph&idSite=151&period=range&date=2015-06-01,2015-07-16&disableLink=1&widget=1&token_auth=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&columns=nb_visits,nb_pageviews&show_footer=0`

I'd like to customize the widget appearance:

1. disable the series picker
2. disable the legend for some of the widgets
3. remove the box-shadow and border of the widget

What's the easiest and best approach without reinventing the wheel of the Widgetize plugin?

Comment: Really good question. I am looking for the same thing. How did you find this `show_footer` parameter?

Comment: I referenced your question in a Matomo forum question: https://forum.matomo.org/t/what-are-the-embedded-widget-parameters/29772